# Python, how to get the unique sets from a group of sets

Tags: python, set, unique

I have a group of sets, let's say, `set1={1,2},set2={2,1},se3={1,3},set4={1,3},set5={1,4}`.
I'd like to get the unique sets from this group of sets. namely, I'd like to obtain the result like: `[{1,2},{1,3},{1,4}]`.

I tried with:

```
myList=[set1,set2,set3,set4,set5]

result=np.unique(np.array(myList))
```

This way works well with the given example, but it seems that it didn't work well when I have a large number of sets.

Is there any better solution?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. "but it seems that it didn't work well when I have a large number of sets." **What does this mean**? What goes wrong when you try this? Is it just slow? Does it give the wrong result? Is there an error?

Comment: If you use `frozenset`s instead you can add them to another set which will then only contain the unique immutable sets.

Comment: The bigger issue here is, if this list of sets was not properly sorted (as it is in the OP) then `np.unique` can give duplicate results. The answer from @tobias_k clears up both issues

Answer (score 2):

As suggested in comments: Convert the `set`s to `frozenset`s so they are immutable and thus hashable and can be put into another `set` (which would not be possible with `set`s):

```
>>> sets = [{1,2}, {2,1}, {1,3}, {1,3}, {1,4}]
>>> set(map(frozenset, sets))
{frozenset({1, 4}), frozenset({1, 3}), frozenset({1, 2})}
```

If you need them as mutable `set`s, you can convert back to `set` afterwards:

```
>>> list(map(set, set(map(frozenset, sets))))
[{1, 4}, {1, 3}, {1, 2}]
```

Or map `frozenset` to original `set` in a `dict` and then get the values from that:

```
>>> list({frozenset(x): x for x in sets}.values())
[{1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}]
```